# Can you define "me" in Gmail search?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

In Gmail you can search for e.g. `to:me` to find emails sent to you. From what I gather, this search finds emails sent to `yourname@gmail.com`, `your.name@gmail.com`, `yourname+tag@gmail.com` etc. But can you add outside, non-Gmail email address (e.g. work addresses) to be included in "me"? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, however not by using any kind of filter.

If you have the account added in the settings menu under the "Accounts and Imports" tab of the settings then the emails will appear in the `to:me` search.

I have confirmed this works as this is how I do it.